# Comparing two folders - Template versus actual

Tags: c#, directoryinfo

I am trying to compare a template folder with subfolders with an existing directory structure. I am trying to recursively iterate through all the sub folders in each directory. My code is as follows.

```
public void compareDirectories(DirectoryInfo Templatedir, DirectoryInfo Projectdir)
{
    DirectoryInfo[] recursiveTemplatedirs = Templatedir.GetDirectories("*.*");
    DirectoryInfo[] recursiveProjectdirs = Projectdir.GetDirectories("*.*");

    string recursiveName;
    string projectName;

    foreach (DirectoryInfo recursiveTemplatedir in recursiveTemplatedirs) 
    {
        recursiveName = recursiveTemplatedir.Name.ToString();
        foreach (DirectoryInfo recursiveProjectdir in recursiveProjectdirs)
        {
            projectName = recursiveProjectdir.Name.ToString();
            if (recursiveName == projectName)
            {
                lstTest.Items.Add("Match " + recursiveName);
            }
            else lstTest.Items.Add("No Match " + recursiveName);
        }

        compareDirectories(recursiveTemplatedir, recursiveProjectdir);
    }
}
```

When I try to run this I get the error that recursiveProjectdir does not exist in this context. Any thoughts on how to get this to run?

Comment: Step through your code.  Are both parameters getting passed to `compasreDirectories` not null?

Comment: recursiveProjectdir is only valid in the second foreach scope.

Comment: You can't run this, you're stuck at compiling this.

Comment: If you're only concerned with the directories the you could probably avoid this code altogether by using [Directory.EnumerateDirectories](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd383462.aspx). Note: Only available in .NET 4.

Answer (score 3):

You are getting error because scope of `recursiveProjectdir` is only inside `foreach loop`

```
foreach (DirectoryInfo recursiveTemplatedir in recursiveTemplatedirs) 
    {
        recursiveName = recursiveTemplatedir.Name.ToString();
        foreach (DirectoryInfo recursiveProjectdir in recursiveProjectdirs)
        {
        }
        //recursiveProjectdir doesn't exists outside the foreach loop
        compareDirectories(recursiveTemplatedir, recursiveProjectdir);
    }
```

Comment: Is there a method I can pass recursiveProjectdir out of the foreach loop. Ultimately, I am trying to compare directories in both locations and then change ACL permissions on the existing directories with ACL permissions set on the template directories.

Comment: `recursiveProjectdir` is inside foreach loop. Which instance of `recursiveProjectdir` do you want to use outside foreach? You can simply declare a variable outside foreach and assign it value inside foreach. In this way you can use `recursiveProjectdir` outside foreach

Answer (score 0):

Move the last compareDirectories inside foreach loop. Just modified your method for testing.

```
public static void compareDirectories(DirectoryInfo Templatedir, DirectoryInfo Projectdir)
{
    DirectoryInfo[] recursiveTemplatedirs = Templatedir.GetDirectories("*.*");
    DirectoryInfo[] recursiveProjectdirs = Projectdir.GetDirectories("*.*");

    string recursiveName;
    string projectName;

    foreach (DirectoryInfo recursiveTemplatedir in recursiveTemplatedirs) 
    {
        recursiveName = recursiveTemplatedir.Name.ToString();
        foreach (DirectoryInfo recursiveProjectdir in recursiveProjectdirs)
        {
            projectName = recursiveProjectdir.Name.ToString();
            if (recursiveName == projectName) {
              Console.WriteLine("Match " + recursiveName);
            } else 
              Console.WriteLine("No Match " + recursiveName);

        compareDirectories(recursiveTemplatedir, recursiveProjectdir);
        }

    }
}
```